# Unable to parse JSON filename object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, parsing

I am unable to parse a JSON object (whatever.png) for some reason, I get **[object%20Object]** which is strange as I never have this issue, as its clearly simple to resolve or stringify and debug if in doubt.

My jQuery code:

```
$(function () {});
$.ajax({
    url: '/shouts/get/ajax',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (res) {
        res.forEach((element, i) => {
            data = {
                message: element['message'],
                date: element['date'],
                descr: element['descr'],
                last_login: element['last_login'],
                added: element['added'],
                user: element['user'],
                username: element['username'],
                user_id: element['user_id'],
                avatar: element['avatar'],
                badges: element.badges
            }

            var result = XBBCODE.process({
                text: data.message,
                removeMisalignedTags: false,
                addInLineBreaks: false
            });

            let allstring = '<div class="shoutbox-container"><span class="shoutDate" style="width:95px">' + jQuery.timeago(data.date) + ' <span style="color:#b3b3b3">ago</span><span id="user_badge_' + i + '"></span></span><span class="shoutUser"><a class="tooltip-shoutuser" title="' + data.username + '" href="/user/?id=' + data.user_id + '"><img src="' + data.avatar + '" class="shout-avatar" /></a></span><span class="shoutText">' + result.html + '</span></div><br>';
            document.getElementById('shoutbox').innerHTML += allstring;

            let badges = [];
            data.badges.forEach(badge => {
                badges.push('<img src="/images/avatars_gear/' + badge + '">').innerHTML += badges; // <--- Object bug
            });

            badges.forEach(badge => {
                document.getElementById('user_badge_' + i).innerHTML += badge;
            });

        });

        $('.shoutbox-container').filter(function () {
            return $(this).children().length === 3;
        }).filter(':odd').addClass('shoutbox_alt');

        $('.shoutbox-container').each(function () {
            $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, this.rowSpan - 1).addClass('shoutbox_alt');
        });

        $('.tooltip-shoutuser').tooltipster({
            animation: 'grow',
            delay: 200,
            theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
        });
    }
});
```

JSON output from PHP:

```
[
  {
    "badges": [],
    "username": "tula966",
    "message": "perk added for [url=/user/?id=39691]tula966[/url]",
    "avatar": "images/avatars/0f885488eb90548b5b93899615c5b838d2300bdb_thumb.jpg",
    "date": "2022-02-04 01:00:01",
    "last_login": "2022-02-03 12:36:06",
    "user_id": "39691"
  },
  {
    "badges": [
      {
        "image": "star.png",
        "descr": " Star Power"
      },
      {
        "image": "toolbox.png",
        "descr": "Worker"
      }
    ],
    "username": "Tminus4",
    "message": "testing testing",
    "avatar": "images/avatars/8cc11eb4cb12c3d7e00abfba341c30b32ced49be_thumb.jpg",
    "date": "2022-02-04 01:00:00",
    "last_login": "2022-02-03 10:52:08",
    "user_id": "1"
  }
]
```

**badge** is not pushing the PNG file names from the JSON response to the DIV. I cant figure this out. This same code structure works perfectly on 3 other areas using the same JSON structure and logic, in fact more complex in our Site Polls area without any issues.

I also attempted to force the object with json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) on the PHP side, which breaks the JS - and I have never needed to utilize that before in any case.

However this seems to differ greatly in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `avatars_gear/' + badge.image + '">')` since you're trying to get the path, not the object?

Comment: Picking up on what @evolutionxbox said, the entries in your `badges` array are *objects* with `image` and `descr` properties, but you're using the object itself with `+`, which will (with plain objects) result in the string you're seeing, `"[object Object]"`. Also, unrelated, but what's the point of the `data` object? Why not just use `element` directly? (Also, `data` seems to be an undeclared variable.)